# Does spring cloud stream and spring cloud starter stream kafka works with spring boot 1.4.2.RELEASE?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to run spring boot application with spring cloud stream and kafka using spring boot version 1.4.2.RELEASE. However, the application failed on startup. If I change spring boot version from 1.4.2.RELEASE to 1.5.12.RELEASE, I can run project normally. So are there're anyway to use spring cloud stream and kafka with spring boot 1.4.2.RELEASE or references that spring boot 1.4.2 is not compatible with spring cloud stream and kafka?


Here's the **build.gradle** file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.4.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Edgware.RELEASE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream'
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka'
}
```

Comment: I am afraid you are asking about very old (EOL) versions that we no longer support. Further more you're not mentioning the version of Spring Cloud Stream, Kafka etc, making it impossible to answer your question. Also, keep in mind that Boot 1.5.x is about to be EOL. We are in boot 2.1.2 at this current moment.

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky I'm sorry since I'm using dependencyManagement here wouldn't it automatically pull out the version base on dependency **Spring Cloud Dependency:Edgware.RELEASE** here? Anyway, the version of Spring Cloud Starter Stream Kafka and Spring Cloud Stream in this case is 1.3.0.

Comment: You should use Spring Cloud `Greenwich.RELEASE` - that is the latest

Comment: Like you've said, Spring Boot version 1 is almost EOL, so  the latest version of spring cloud here would unlikely support this version(`1.4.2`). So here, I'm just trying to find if there is any version that works with spring boot v1.4.2.